# Eclipse: "package...does not exist" when building a Maven package that references a class in another project

Tags: eclipse, maven, build, package, project

In Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 2020-12, I have created two projects, "a-test-class-jar" and "a-call-test-class".  In the first of these, I have created a class called "ATestClass" as follows.

```
package com.testclass.maven.a_test_class_jar;

public class ATestClass {
    
    public String getTestResults() {
        
        return "Hello from ATestClass";
        
    }

}
```

```
package com.testclass.maven.a_call_test_class;
import com.testclass.maven.a_test_class_jar.ATestClass;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

        ATestClass hw = new ATestClass();

        System.out.println(hw.getTestResults());

    }

}
```

I have added the "a-test-class-jar" project to the Build Path of the "a-call-test-class" project by

1. Right clicking the "a-call-test-class" project
2. Selecting "Build Path" then "Configure Build Path"
3. Selecting the "Projects" tab, then clicking the "Add" button
4. Checking "a-test-class-jar" from the list of options, then cliking "OK"
5. Clicking "Apply and Close"

After doing the above, when I run the the main method of the App class of the "a-call-test-class", it successfully instantiates the hw method and prints the "Hello from ATestClass" result from the getTestResult method of the "a-test-class-jar" class.

I am able to run "clean package" to build the jar file for the "a-test-class-jar" project.  However, when I try to do the same for the "a-call-test-class" project, I get the following.

"...package com.testclass.maven.a_test_class_jar does not exist"

I have done Google searches for answers including variations on combinations of the terms "eclipse", "maven", "package", and "does not exist" as well as on questions such as "how to build a maven package in eclipse that references classes in other projects".

Some of the results indicated solutions using pom.xml files.  Is this necessary? Is it not sufficient to add the other project to the Build Path as described previously?

Again, when I run the method in Eclipse, it runs successfully, but I get the "package...does not exist" error when I try to build the Maven package. Can somone please tell me what I need to do to build a Maven package that references a class in a package in another Maven project?

Comment: Maven doesn't directly understand the idea of sources in one project of your workspace being compiled against sources in another project in your workspace. Either go all in on Maven, or rip it all out.

Comment: nitind, Thank you for your reply.  Of course, I posted this question to address a more complex issue I am trying to resolve.  I have a Maven project that imports other libraries.  I don't understand how it finds the projects it is importing, but some of them come from other Maven projects.  I am trying to modify the code in one of them, but the imported Class is from another location than the one I have modified, so it isn't finding the one I have modified.  Below, are the import statements.

Comment: /*     */ package org.nhindirect.xd.routing.impl;
/*     */ 
/*     */ import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
/*     */ import org.nhind.config.rest.AddressService;
/*     */ import org.nhindirect.common.rest.exceptions.ServiceException;
/*     */ import org.nhindirect.config.model.Address;

  // import org.nhindirect.xd.routing.impl.Address;

/*     */ import org.nhindirect.config.model.EntityStatus;
/*     */ import org.nhindirect.xd.routing.RoutingResolver;
/*     */ import org.slf4j.Logger;
/*     */ import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

Comment: I have modified code in the org.nhindirect.config.model.Address class, but it seems the code I modified is in a different location from where it is importing this class.

Comment: In the _Java Build Path_ adding a JAR makes it visible in the IDE, but not in Maven. For Maven you have to do the following, which would also be enough for the IDE if your project is a Maven project: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4955635/6505250 By the way, Eclipse 2020-12 is more than three years and 13 releases behind. Please upgrade. Consider following a tutorial to get a better understanding of Java with Maven to manage your project dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  In the actual project I am trying to troubleshoot, I have added the following to the pom.xml file.

Comment: <dependency>
 <groupId>com.config-model</groupId>
 <artifactId>sconfig-model</artifactId>
 <version>6.0.1</version>
 <scope>system</scope>
 <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/config-model-6.0.1.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>

Comment: I created the .../src/main/resources directory and copied the and config-model-6.0.1.jar files from the target directories of the other projects into this directory.

I then tried to perform "clean package" in Eclilpse, but still got...

"cannot find symbol"..."symbol: method helloWorld(String)"

Comment: The helloWorld method is being called from a class with the line, "import org.nhindirect.config.model.Address;".  The Address class is the one to which I added the "helloWorld" method which is in another project.  I compiled that project to create the config-model-6.0.1.jar file which was copied as described earlier.

Comment: I think the import statement above is still pointing to an older version of the Address class instead of the one in the jar file I copied.  How do I get the current class to use the copied jar file instead of the older location?  I also don't quite understand how to know the paths to items being imported by the import statements.  In other words, how can I tell the location of the org.nhindirect.config.model.Address referenced in the import statement?